# MongoDB: How to add this hash to every document in a collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to add a hash like this to every document in my `users` collection:

```
"authorization" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("52712baabe40ac667d000001"),
        "all" : "true",
        "boxscore" : "false",
        "created_at" : ISODate("2013-10-30T15:54:18.397Z"),
        "depth_charts" : "false",
        "fantasy_news" : "false",
        "injuries" : "false",
        "matchups" : "false",
        "news" : "false",
        "odds" : "false",
        "play_by_play" : "false",
        "previews" : "false",
        "recaps" : "false",
        "schedule" : "false",
        "standings" : "false",
        "statistics" : "false",
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2013-11-12T21:47:13.808Z")
    }
```

Some `users` already have this hash, but not all of them. It's okay to overwrite existing users if they already have the document embedded. Is there a way in MongoDB's console using some JavaScript in order to get this done?

I should also note, that this is an embedded document. So `ObjectId` should be unique for each document in the `users` collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.users.update({}, {$set: {authorization:  {
        "_id" : ObjectId(),
        "all" : "true",
        "boxscore" : "false",
        "created_at" : ISODate("2013-10-30T15:54:18.397Z"),
        "depth_charts" : "false",
        "fantasy_news" : "false",
        "injuries" : "false",
        "matchups" : "false",
        "news" : "false",
        "odds" : "false",
        "play_by_play" : "false",
        "previews" : "false",
        "recaps" : "false",
        "schedule" : "false",
        "standings" : "false",
        "statistics" : "false",
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2013-11-12T21:47:13.808Z")
    }}}, {multi: true})
```

Comment: Is embedding an `_id` in this case smart? I'm assuming one would get auto generated if it gets omitted (which is probably the correct way of going about this?

Comment: Yeah, it's an embedded document -- going to guess that it'll just get auto generated?

Comment: if the doc is part of the user doc, then it wont get auto generated, only auto generated on insert of a new doc, if you want to generate one yourself just say new ObjectId() updated the code to show you